# Regular representation of $Z_3$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, cyclic-groups

Is there a choice of the basis of $\mathbb{C}Z_3$ such that the regular representation of $Z_3$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} w&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix} \text{and}\begin{pmatrix} w^2&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
where $w$ is a primitive $3$rd root of unity.

I haven't found one for this. Based on [cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068508/regular-representation-of-the-cyclic-group-of-order-3) I do have found a basis for:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&w^2&0\\0&0&w \end{pmatrix} \text{and}\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&w&0\\0&0&w^2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: The generator $t$ acts trivially on the second and the third base vectors, which means they are both of the form $k+kt+kt^2$ and are not linearly independent. So there is no such basis.

Comment: The answer is no: just look at the trace.

Comment: Thank you for the input. But there is indeed such a group in $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{C})$... So it is not a representation of $Z_3$? I can't make sense of it...

Comment: It is a representation but not the regular one.

Comment: Ahhh... OK. What representation is it?

Comment: sorry, I got it now. was being stupid.